# Rake task for creating database records for all existing ActiveStorage variants

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

In Rails 6.1, ActiveStorage creates database records for all variants when they're loaded for the first time: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37901

I'd like to enable this, but since I have tens of thousands of files in my production Rails app, it'd be problematic (and presumably slow) to have users creating so many database records as they browse the site. Is there a way to write a Rake task that'll iterate through every attachment in my database, and generate the variants and save them in the database?

I'd run that once, after enabling the new `active_storage.track_variants` config, and then any newly-uploaded files would be saved when they're loaded for the first time.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the Rake task I ended up creating for this. The Parallel stuff can be removed if you have a smaller dataset, but I found that with 70k+ variants it was intolerably slow when doing it without any parallelization. You can also ignore the progress bar-related code :)

Essentially, I just take all the models that have an attachment (I do this manually, you could do it in a more dynamic way if you have a ton of attachments), and then filter the ones that are not variable. Then I go through each attachment and generate a variant for each size I've defined, and then call `process` on it to force it to be saved to the database.

Make sure to catch MiniMagick (or vips, if you prefer) errors in the task so that a bad image file doesn't break everything.

```rb
# Rails 6.1 changes the way ActiveStorage works so that variants are
# tracked in the database. The intent of this task is to create the
# necessary variants for all game covers and user avatars in our database.
# This way, the user isn't creating dozens of variant records as they
# browse the site. We want to create them ahead-of-time, when we deploy
# the change to track variants.
namespace 'active_storage:vglist:variants' do
  require 'ruby-progressbar'
  require 'parallel'

  desc "Create all variants for covers and avatars in the database."
  task create: :environment do
    games = Game.joins(:cover_attachment)
    # Only attempt to create variants if the cover is able to have variants.
    games = games.filter { |game| game.cover.variable? }
    puts 'Creating game cover variants...'

    # Use the configured max number of threads, with 2 leftover for web requests.
    # Clamp it to 1 if the configured max threads is 2 or less for whatever reason.
    thread_count = [(ENV.fetch('RAILS_MAX_THREADS', 5).to_i - 2), 1].max

    games_progress_bar = ProgressBar.create(
      total: games.count,
      format: "\e[0;32m%c/%C |%b>%i| %e\e[0m"
    )

    # Disable logging in production to prevent log spam.
    Rails.logger.level = 2 if Rails.env.production?

    Parallel.each(games, in_threads: thread_count) do |game|
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
        begin
          [:small, :medium, :large].each do |size|
            game.sized_cover(size).process
          end
        # Rescue MiniMagick errors if they occur so that they don't block the
        # task from continuing.
        rescue MiniMagick::Error => e
          games_progress_bar.log "ERROR: #{e.message}"
          games_progress_bar.log "Failed on game ID: #{game.id}"
        end
        games_progress_bar.increment
      end
    end

    games_progress_bar.finish unless games_progress_bar.finished?

    users = User.joins(:avatar_attachment)
    # Only attempt to create variants if the avatar is able to have variants.
    users = users.filter { |user| user.avatar.variable? }
    puts 'Creating user avatar variants...'

    users_progress_bar = ProgressBar.create(
      total: users.count,
      format: "\e[0;32m%c/%C |%b>%i| %e\e[0m"
    )

    Parallel.each(users, in_threads: thread_count) do |user|
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
        begin
          [:small, :medium, :large].each do |size|
            user.sized_avatar(size).process
          end
        # Rescue MiniMagick errors if they occur so that they don't block the
        # task from continuing.
        rescue MiniMagick::Error => e
          users_progress_bar.log "ERROR: #{e.message}"
          users_progress_bar.log "Failed on user ID: #{user.id}"
        end
        users_progress_bar.increment
      end
    end

    users_progress_bar.finish unless users_progress_bar.finished?
  end
end
```

This is what the `sized_cover` looks like in `game.rb`:

```rb
def sized_cover(size)
  width, height = COVER_SIZES[size]
  cover&.variant(
    resize_to_limit: [width, height]
  )
end
```

`sized_avatar` is pretty much the same thing.